# Changing cell colour if calculated value in the cell changes based

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 2 worksheets in the same spreadsheet and 2nd worksheet dates are based on 1st worksheet with various `vlookup`. Now, I have known how to change the cell color if calculated value in the cell changes:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Interior.Color = 3
End Sub
```

When I use this `VBA` in the 2nd worksheet and change the 1st worksheet, the cell color in the 2nd worksheet will not change. I want cells with a formula in the 2nd worksheet to change their color when I manually update the 1st worksheet.
Is it possible? Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvTe2.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6GGt.jpg)

Comment: Could you add a practical example, some sample data, some screenshots, and some information about the formulas (are they in the same cells as the cells on the first worksheet)? You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67140179/edit) your question at any time.

Comment: Worksheet_Change() takes place only if you change a cell manually, not calculated value changes.

Comment: This sounds more like a job for [conditional formatting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f).

Answer (score 2):

I'll guess a solution: as your VBA code in 2nd Worksheet will have not effect, as we have not user triggering. So in your first Worksheet, we can do something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Worksheets("Name_Of_2nd_Worksheet").Range(Target.Address()).Interior.Color = _
        RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

When you change something in 1st worksheet, the second worksheet will change filling color.

---

The second solution more complex but closer to your requirement. It uses VBA `Worksheet_Calculate()` event in 2nd sheet, please remove all VBA from 1st worksheet first, like this:

```vb
Private Function getActualUsedRange(ByVal strVLookUp)
  Set getActualUsedRange = Range("A1").Resize(Cells.Find(what:=strVLookUp, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlFormulas).Row, _
    Cells.Find(what:=strVLookUp, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlFormulas).Column)
End Function

'
' change color of all cells with formulas containing some string:
'
' strVLookUp: vlookup
' strFirstAddress: address of first cell, like $C$5
' objCell: range object of 1 cell
' objRange: range object of cells with formulas
' lBackColor: long for color index
'
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

  Dim strVLookUp As String, strFirstAddress As String
  Dim objCell As Object, objRange As Object
  Dim lBackColor As Long

  ' search this string in formulas in 2nd Worksheet:
  strVLookUp = "vlookup"

  ' change back color as you want:
  lBackColor = RGB(255, 150, 0)

  ' get whole range with formulas involving "vlookup":
  Set objRange = getActualUsedRange(strVLookUp)
  
  ' if we find a range, loop over it:
  If Not objRange Is Nothing Then
  
    Set objCell = objRange.Find(strVLookUp, LookIn:=xlFormulas)
    
    If Not objCell Is Nothing Then
    
      strFirstAddress = objCell.Address
      
      Do
        objCell.Interior.Color = lBackColor
        Set objCell = objRange.FindNext(objCell)
      Loop While Not objCell Is Nothing And objCell.Address <> strFirstAddress
      
    End If

    ' free memory:
    Set objCell = Nothing
    Set objRange = Nothing
    '
  End If
'
End Sub
```

This is based on the following fact: in the 2nd Worksheet, some cells have formulas like this: =vlookup("MyValue", ...), you referenced the vlookup() function.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer, I have change the VBA code like you post, but when I change the 1st worksheet, 2nd worksheet' color is still no change....even I change the 1st worksheet, there is no color change..

Comment: Hello! I have solved the second question: I change the 1st worksheet, there is no color change. But the first question is still exists. Because 2nd cell data are not in the same cells as the cells on the first worksheet... could you tell me what should I do?

Comment: You can find the cell address in the 2nd sheet with row,column expression, for example, $C$10, column C, row 10, like this: Worksheets("Name_Of_2nd_Worksheet").Range("$C$10").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

Comment: But another question is that there are thousands of data in each worksheet. I can not check every cell of data one by one... during this time, I learn about the calculate can read the formula's result, and could we follow this idea...? And anyway, thanks for your help and answer!

Comment: Excuse me, could you mean that I need to change all "strWorksheetName1" to my worksheet name such as "Sheet 1"? and if the situation like the picture in my re-edit question,  should I change the code like this:   
Dim Sheet1 As String, $A$1 As String
  Dim A1 As Range, A1:B24 As Object
I am sorry for my ignorance, and really thanks for your help.

Comment: No, just strWorksheetName1 = "Sheet 1" in VBA code, not your Worksheets, vba is invisible, so a background thing that supports Visible things, here Worksheets.

Comment: I'm sorry to disturb you again. I'm a rookie T_T So, would you mean that I just need to add "strworksheetname1 = sheet 1" before "Private Sub Worksheet_calculate()"? The rest of the code doesn't need to be changed, right?

Comment: With pleasure, I've modified the code, in the new code there is no worksheet name required. Please copy the code as a whole, then test it, and then adapt it to your use.